# Not able to use the camera inside docker as well not able to access the microphone

Tags: python, linux, docker, computer-vision, fedora

I have created a model that can detect Eyes and faces using the haarcascades. This model is working perfectly in my local machine both windows and fedora. But when I try to run in it docker it shows an error [image: Available platform plugins are:xcb is the error].

This error is coming when I run this cmd [docker run -it --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 image_name]

Also I have used the pyttsx3 module for speak text in the python code, but sound is also not coming.

Here is the Dockerfile Code:---

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /root/Projects/Docker_Projects
COPY . .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install speake3 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo
RUN sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 -y
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y
RUN apt-get install 'ffmpeg'\
    'libsm6'\
    'libxext6' -y
RUN sudo apt-get install alsa-base -y
RUN sudo apt-get install alsa-utils -y
#RUN apt-get install qt5-default
RUN apt install espeak -y
RUN apt-get install alsa-utils -y
RUN pip install opencv-python 
CMD ["python","Computer_Vision.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* an SE Linux error. By default, the security policy prevents containers from accessing devices directly (because that's a huge potential route for container escape or other exploits).

You should be able to use audit2allow to create a rule that permits this. (Or, of course, you can `sudo setenforce 0` — that's a fine way to test that this is the problem, but I do recommend creating the specific policy once you've got it figured out so that you have all of the protections selinux gives.)

I don't have a handy example for a video device, but here's an example with a USB serial device I set up for Home Assistant open source home automation software running in a container. (I'm using podman rather than docker, but the basic principles should be the same.) In my systemd journal, I see a bunch of log entries from the audit subsystem about AVCs.

The command `sudo journalctl --boot _TRANSPORT=audit -g '^AVC`'  will show these specifically (or you can use just grep, or whatever). `--boot` means to show since the last system boot; you might want to narrow it down further. Anyway, I get a bunch of lines like:

```
Feb 01 17:45:13 example.org audit[15371]: AVC avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=15371 comm="node" name="ttyUSB0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=735 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c214,c987 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usbtty_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
Feb 01 17:45:13 example.org audit[15371]: AVC avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=15371 comm="node" path="/dev/zwave" dev="devtmpfs" ino=735 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c214,c987 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usbtty_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
Feb 01 17:45:13 example.org audit[15371]: AVC avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=15371 comm="node" path="/dev/zwave" dev="devtmpfs" ino=735 ioctlcmd=0x5401 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c214,c987 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usbtty_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
Feb 01 17:45:13 example.org audit[15371]: AVC avc:  denied  { lock } for  pid=15371 comm="node" path="/dev/zwave" dev="devtmpfs" ino=735 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c214,c987 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usbtty_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
```

The good news is: you don't *really* have to understand that in detail. Just make sure everything you see relates to the device in question (easy to add `grep` to make sure), and then pipe that to `audit2allow`, like this:

```
sudo journalctl --boot _TRANSPORT=audit -g '^AVC' | 
    audit2allow -m containervideo >  containervideo.te
```

Then, build the module and load it:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile containervideo.pp
semodule -i containervideo.pp
```

This will install the `containervideo.pp` policy into your local config. You won't need to keep them around later.

Comment: I am having error when i run this command inside dockerfile.

Comment: Yes, that is a likely symptom. I can't see the exact error because it's a screenshot and my eyes aren't that good — it'd be  helpful if you could copy the _exact_ text of the message into your question. But, the symptom will be that while the permissions look fine inside the container, access doesn't actually work. _Outside_ the container, you will see SELinux alerts (called "AVC"s in the jargon) in the log.

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to write make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile containervideo.pp
semodule -i containervideo.pp

Comment: The previous command — piping the journal output to `audit2allow` _should_ generate source file. Run that `make` command in the same directory. You can either do it in a temporary space, or some work environment where you save it. (I'd definitely test with `sudo setenforce 0` first to make sure my instinct is right, though.)

Comment: Yes I have run the previous command and containervideo.te is generated in my working folder. Now what I need to do?

Comment: Is there a problem with the command I gave? I make mistakes sometimes. What happens?